# iPhone - changing contents of a UITableViewCell inside a navigationController

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView with some cells in it that have people's names. When the user clicks on a cell, the Navigation Controller pushes a new view onto the stack that shows detailed info for that person. When the user is done and clicks the button to return to the previous view, the tableview is again shown. The problem is that I want to edit the cell text (or just mark the cell in some way) to show that the user has clicked on that cell. In my cellForRowAtIndexPath: method I have set up code that should change the text of the cell after a user clicks on that cell. I set up break points and it IS entering cellForRowAtIndexPath: when the detail view is popped and the tableview is again shown. It's entering the segment of code in cellForRowAtIndexPath: that should change the text, but when it comes up on screen, the text has not been changed. Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going on? Thanks.

**EDIT: I figured it out. I just needed to call [tableView reloadData]; instead of calling the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.** Not sure why that works differently, but it fixed it.

Comment: You should write a real answer yourself and accept your own answer, so the question is closed.

Comment: I can't for another few hours because I don't have enough karma but I will, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'll help you out. You don't need to credit me with the answer though.

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

that method is called within the framework when a cell is being refreshed from the queue or when it needs to be created. You should not call this method.

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

that method is basically a refresh on all of the visible cells show in the UITableView. This is the method you should call if you change information in your data source or you need to (force) update the appearance of your cells.

Answer (score 0):

It's Good You Have Reload Table And Changed The Text But If YouJustIndicate NAd Don't Want To Change The Text The nYou Can Use elow Given Text ....

[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

It Will Check Mark Particuler Cell Which You Click/Visited......

Hope You Like This Solution.....